# Need a peephole camera without modifying peephole

Tags: electrical, doors, security, doorbell, ip-camera

I searched almost everywhere. Here is my issue. I live in an apt. I cannot modify or remove the peephole. I can't add a video doorbells of any kind. I am looking to see how I can put a camera on the inside of the door and have a video or who is outside my apt. I have tried with a smart phone on zoom and it works but I need that smartphone and buying a expensive phone for this is just too expensive. I found several people who used a wyze camera but they modified the camera. How can wyze v3 or any other device I can use to see the view from the peephole? What type of camera would work or a lens or anything you can think of that might work. Thanks!

Comment: What prevents you from adding a video doorbell, that would not prevent you from adding a video peephole?

Comment: Why not use the Wyze camera with modifications if that's the feature set you're after.

Comment: Do a web search for "no drill door camera" ... I'm specifically referring to the mounts that seem to "wrap around" the door and cannot be removed without the door being open. (I am assuming that the covenant against a video doorbell is the modification of the existing doorbell not being allowed, and not against video itself)

Comment: No making changes of look of the outside. Maybe that js why no one had that no drill video.  I don't know which lens would work for the wyze and don't want to open  the camera. If someone knows what lens would work without opening wyze that be good

Comment: For the smartphone app they won't use the better lens of my phone i message one of them to be able to use my better zoom lens but they said they don't. Now I forgot what he said but they have to make it for every phone so they don't let you choose the lens.

Answer (score 14):

You've fallen into a wrong set of assumptions:

- the only smartphone-like thing with a camera IS a smart phone
- all smartphones must be 0-2 years old and costly
- all smartphones need a costly cellular plan to function.

None of these are true.

Tablets have cameras just like phones. (not necessarily flash).

Old cellphones are dirt cheap.

All smart phones can operate on WiFi-only with no contract/plan.

In fact, this is why Apple killed the iPod; there's no difference between the iPod Touch and an old iPhone with no plan. Except the old iPhone can call 911/112/999. (no plan required for that).

So, since you have found a way to make smart phones do the job... you can proceed with any old tablet or smart phone with the plan turned off, and set to WiFi only.  People all over have them in drawers. The older Android units even have replaceable batteries!

As far as physically attaching to the door, look into 3M Command strips to hang a frame of your own construction.

Comment: Personally, I found that when it comes to cameras, buying a 3-4 years old, used, flagship or high-end phone is usually the most economical when it comes to a good camera, at least when it comes to Android.

Comment: Well, Apple killed the iPod because it was a shortcut to get a high-end, up-to-date iPhone for 75% off the price if you didn't care about having a cell modem in it.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, rather than trusting Android software on obsolete hardware to do this, I'd get a cheap (<£/$10) USB webcam and a Raspberry Pi (similar price for the Pi Zero, plus power supply and case).  This is a miniature full Linux computer so can talk to any webcam, process images, and upload over WiFi.

You can test the webcam first using a laptop; even some phones will show an external USB camera with the right adaptors.

This is a common application for the Raspberry Pi.  There are plenty of tutorials and even a dedicated security camera operating system (MotionOS).  As the Pi outputs to HDMI, with a suitable camera you can directly view the video feed on a monitor or TV when you're at home, as well as taking advantage of its connectivity.

Comment: Rather than trusting tried-and-tested Android on old-ish hardware, you recommend that an average person dives into Linux?? Thank you for the laugh!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus So one has to be above-average to use a Linux? I'll take that as a compliment ;-).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it looks like there are pretty much turnkey solutions for this.  And I've found out the hard way that running an app on an old version of Android can lead to the software giving up with no prospect of a fix (e.g. the API used in the old OS is deprecated, and had to be dropped to support newer versions.  Once you get into side-loading old releases you might wish you'd gone for something configurable in the first place.

Comment: You could also try Win10 IOT core (officially supported on the Pi) or [tricking Win11 into installing(https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/install-windows-11-raspberry-pi)

Comment: I would have fun learning pi but don't have the time and it won't solve my problem. The camera still won't see outside and that is my problem

Comment: @ChrisH The average person would throw out the super old phone and buy a new 3 year old-ish phone. Believe me when I tell you that Linux is esoteric no matter how many turn-key solutions get forked.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus what turnkey solutions? The peephole cameras I found require removing the peephole so no good. Can you name a turnkey

Comment: @GreenGiant Beats me, read Chris H's comment and ask him. I just know that Linux isn't for the average person, that's all.

Comment: @ChrisH what turnkey solutions? Are you talking about the peephole cameras that exist. They all require removing the old one

Comment: @GreenGiant A software turnkey solution - install the distro, plug in the camera, which will see outside if you can attach it to the inside of the peephole.  You've (or rather your landlord has) ruled out the far better hardware solution.  A webcam lens is similar enough to a phone camera lens that it will work.

Comment: And @MonkeyZeus if you tried it 20 years ago, when I first did, that may have been true.  A modern distribution is easy to install and set up on suitable hardware - like the RPi which was designed for it - with no prior knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You could mount a borescope to the peephole. They can be gotten in USB format, also with their own screen and other configurations.  I have seen them for under $25.00. I would guess the other electronics will cost much more then the borescope. I purchased one about two years ago, it works great and the cable is very flexible.  I simply plug it into a computer and it displays the image. This would be a good use for an old computer. There is a lot of software available that will record what it picks up, some of it may even trigger with motion. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks looked into boroscope and they are not wifi. Not sure where I read it, been all over said something about not being able to see far with it. Plus don't have a old computer to use

Comment: @GreenGiant borescopes can't see far, that's kind of the point.  But the lens in the peephole might deal with that.  And see my answer for a new computer that costs less than you might end up spending on cables

Comment: @Chris I could not find your answer about a new computer that costs less than... can you post again? Do boroscipes come with their own screen? If they do can I put a motion camera like blink or wyze in front of the screen so it notices movement and the security camera will let me know

Comment: @GreenGiant [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/251877/21138).  Some borescopes have a little screen, but pointing cameras at screens for motion detection is going to get really annoying really fast.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the peep hole, unscrew it.

You might have to cut the paint around the perimeter using sharp blade and holding it in 45 Dgr angle. No damage done

It is screwed in from both sides.

Insert peephole camera made for this application.

[image: pinhole]

Best would be battery operated WiFi camera that works with your phone, no wires.

Comment: Wait what inn part? I have stuck a q tip inside to clean and I can stick my finger a little bit. The lens outside and I can't remove either side

Comment: @GreenGiant they are screwed on, from both sides of the door.

Comment: Makes sense because there is a metal tube but no lens on inside just outside. Anyways I can remove it as it's painted and they won't do it for me.

Comment: @GreenGiant use sharp blade and cut the paint off around the perimeter holding the blade in 45 Dgr. It wont be visible afterward. Now unscrew it. and insert pinhole camera specifically made for this.

Comment: In your own house, this would work great. (Of course then installing a video doorbell would be possible too.) But in an apartment building with a draconian landlord, getting caught in the act of changing the peephole, or getting caught afterwards because it looks different, could be cause for breaking the lease. And in a tight housing market getting a new tenant is a way to raise the rent (often can't do that easily otherwise) and/or get rid of a "problem" tenant.

Comment: Sorry for not replying to all each comment. I can't modfy the peephole its not worth issues with the complex. I was hoping to find a better solution than the smart phone. Used ones are cheap but they get hot if left plugged in. Plus I know it cold be improved with a wifi camera. I read wyze website where people are doing but no one mentions which lens to buy and I don't know anything about lens. Plus they all open the camera and I don't want to so I can return them if the camera has issued. Plus maybe there is a better camera.

Comment: @GreenGiant so you just want to see who is at the door, a friend or Foe  Use a movable rubber door stop, it costs pennies, it will allow you to open the door slightly then shut it in someones face.

Comment: More of when I am not at home and for stupid ups fedex that leave the package even when I tell them i am home just knock. They say they will but don't. Then notify you later. Plus I had a few door testers so I can see who and talk to them so they would run away

Comment: The phone getting a little warm wouldn't matter.  But if you're worried about that, run the charger off a timer so it's not  on all the time.  Phones are nice and flat for mounting, unlike most wifi cameras.  software should exist though I'm no expert.